# jQuery: Slide toggle to the left

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, slidetoggle

With the following jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Kb7Fp/

How would I show the content with an animation sliding from the right to the left?

MS Visual Studio debugger is giving me: Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method '[object Object]' when I use  $`(this).children('div').show("slide", { direction: "left" }, 1000);`

The jQuery documentation for `slideToggle` doesn't really cover directions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use .show("...") in that rich form, you may need to download the JqueryUI plugin [here](http://jqueryui.com/download) as a support.

See the result here: http://jsfiddle.net/Alex_seed/Kb7Fp/22/

Of course, without plugin, you can also assemble the effect with existing jquery functions. Have a glance at those threads:

http://www.dynamicdrive.com/forums/showthread.php?t=41329
http://www.codingforums.com/showthread.php?t=157709

Hope these would help